# How to insert 1 if value in a cell is different than previous cell and 2 if value is the same

Tags: excel

I know the answer is easy, but I can't understand why it doesn't work.

I have Column A: that contains a Project Number and Column B: that contains Group ID (of project).

A Project can have multiple groups and I want to count and display the desired result (group #) in Column C: starting from one rather than a random number that the Group ID has assigned.

Ex:
[image: desired result in Column C]

I need to input 1 in Column C until the group ID changes and 2 only if the group ID changes but the Project Number is still the same. Input 3 if the group ID changes 3 times and the project number is still the same and so on.

Here's what I tried

```
=IF(A2=A1,1,IF(B2=B1,1,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:A2=A2)/(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,$B$2:B2)+($A$2:A2<>A2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In C3 :

```
=IF(B4<>B3,1,IF(AND(B4<>B3,A4=A3),2,IF(AND(B2<>B3,A2=A3,B4<>B3,A4=A3),3)))
```